# Override Google+ (Google Plus) mobile website redirect

Tags: url, google-plus

Is there a way to force the desktop version of a Google+ page, using URL parameters (or something else)?

For example, this URL is to a Google+ Local page, which is fine on desktop:
https://plus.google.com/107958373256144660254/about

But on a mobile device, it redirects to https://plus.google.com/app/basic/107958373256144660254/about with a stripped down version of the Google+ Local page. Is there a way to force the page at this URL to look like the desktop version? Something like https://plus.google.com/app/basic/107958373256144660254/about**?mobile=false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gady there is no documented way to do this.  It appears that the Google+ site is redirecting based on user-agent.

Comment: Based on how much time has gone by without any change from Google on this, I think your answer is going to hold for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Want to force desktop view of google plus when on a tablet? Try https://plus.google.com/?fd=1

The ?fb=1 part foces desktop on mobile devices.

Comment: Your example has "fd=1", but you also mention "fb=1". Neither of these cases seem to work for specific Google+ Local pages. https://plus.google.com/107958373256144660254/about?fd=1 and https://plus.google.com/107958373256144660254/about?fb=1 and https://plus.google.com/107958373256144660254/about all end up on the mobile version of the page.